# error conexion vue-socket ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

I have not managed to connect my vue js to my nodejs server. The configuration is the following, server side:

```
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5050);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), () => console.log(`http://localhost:${app.get('port')}`));
```

on the client side:

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketio({
 debug: true,
 connection: 'http://localhost:5050'
}));
```

when I test in local everything works perfect, the socket opens the events are issued without failure, the problem lies when I upload a server, the constant error:

> vue-socketio.js:1 GET `http://localhost:5050/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MUu_7m4` net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

try to put the ip of the server provider and still the problem, I have seen many issues regarding this but I can not get a clear solution, I appreciate the help they can give me, thanks!

Comment: _"try to put the ip of the server provider"_  good... _"and still the problem"_  please update your question with what you tried here as well as any error messages

Comment: @Phil The error error is exactly the same as I show. with the ip of the server and in localhost the error is the same.

Comment: Are you saying the error message still says `http://localhost...`? Have you set up the remote socket server?

Comment: no, ``vue-socketio.js:1 GET http://xxx.xxx.xxx:5050/socket.io/?EI...`` or ``vue-socketio.js:1 GET http://localhost:5050/socket.io/?EI...`` depending on how you configure it, the error is the same for both cases.